# How to customize a wso2is PAP?

Tags: policy, wso2-identity-server

is there any way to adjust existing PAPs of wso2is to improve the user experience?

I dont wanna change logos or stuff like that, I want to implement some kind of shortcut buttons into an existing PAP.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is possible, If you need to do some changes to management console UI.  You need to change `org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.ui` bundle.  Let me tell you how to do it..

If it is just a JSP file changes,  You can locate the`org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.ui` bundle from the  `repository/components/plugins` directory.  And edit your jsp file and update the jar file.  Then once you restart the server,  you can see the modified UI.

If it is some java source changes. You need to compile the jar file again...

1. find the version of  `org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.ui`  file and locate the source of it from [here](http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/components/identity/org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.ui/)
2. SVN Co the source and build it using Maven 3.0
3. Then you can do the changes and build the jar file again.
4. Copy and replace the existing jar file and Restart the server.

Also,  you can write your own UI using the PAP web service API. In WSO2 IS UI calls the BE API to get the functions done,  Therefore you can write your own UI by automating these web service API.  You can find more details from [here](http://xacmlinfo.org/2013/09/27/xacml-policy-administration/)